# Change the logic of custom type from extra types (PhoneNumber)

Tags: python, pydantic

There is the PhoneNumber type to validate phone numbers:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

from pydantic_extra_types.phone_numbers import PhoneNumber


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    phone_number: PhoneNumber


user = User(name='John', phone_number='+447911123456')
print(user.phone_number)  
#> tel:+44-7911-123456
```

I'm satisfied with it except the unwanted "tel:" prefix. I applied a trick like that:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

from pydantic_extra_types.phone_numbers import PhoneNumber


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    phone_number: PhoneNumber

    @model_validator(mode="after")
    def remove_prefix_from_phone(self) -> "User":
        if self.phone_number:
            self.phone_number = self.phone_number.removeprefix("tel:")
        return self


user = User(name='John', phone_number='+447911123456')
print(user.phone_number)  
#> +44-7911-123456
```

But problem is that I convert the field into str and the PhoneNumber class is not even considered as str subtype unlike EmailStr for example. Seems like it a bad move and MyPy marks it as error as well - incompatible types in assignment (meanwhile, the validation logic is fine).
Maybe I could do it smarter?

I couldn't think of other options but it should be done within the Pydantic model for sure, because I load data from DB in a web-service and prefix would be exist in auto-generated response.

Would be glad for any piece of advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PhoneNumber` class has these class variables:

```
#https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-extra-types/blob/092251d226edcf4e06bbe4f904da177fad20a6de/pydantic_extra_types/phone_numbers.py#L26

default_region_code: str | None = None
phone_format: str = 'RFC3966'
min_length: int = 7
max_length: int = 64
```

If we follow a bunch of code chains, we end up in the `phonenumber` repository that `PhoneNumber` depends on. This is the last stop for your data before being returned as a `PhoneNumber`, We can see that `phone_format` ultimately affects the phone number in the following ways:

```
#https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/2f06ef6db2ca83f3856fbb8019a0c665f5971b13/python/phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py#L1726

def _prefix_number_with_country_calling_code(country_code, num_format, formatted_number):
    """A helper function that is used by format_number and format_by_pattern."""
    if num_format == PhoneNumberFormat.E164:
        return _PLUS_SIGN + unicod(country_code) + formatted_number
    elif num_format == PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL:
        return _PLUS_SIGN + unicod(country_code) + U_SPACE + formatted_number
    elif num_format == PhoneNumberFormat.RFC3966:
        #_RF3966_PREFIX = 'tel:'
        return _RFC3966_PREFIX + _PLUS_SIGN + unicod(country_code) + U_DASH + formatted_number
    else:
        return formatted_number
```

It may be notable that the above returns only the formatted number if you use an unrecognized format. There is a 'NATIONAL' format that is oddly absent from the above conditions. Using it should trigger the `else`.

This should solve your problem.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic_extra_types.phone_numbers import PhoneNumber

PhoneNumber.phone_format = 'E164' #'INTERNATIONAL', 'NATIONAL'

class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    phone_number: PhoneNumber
```

Comment: Thank you, setting the format of a phone number saves the day. And about str inheritance - I didn't notice it when check the class, my bad. 
But I don't understand what is short answer for: "phone_number: PhoneNumber | str" will not work as it should be, because it will take any string as proper object for the field and will not validate the phone number exactly. Probably it's better to remove it to get rid of confusion.

Comment: "will not work as it should be, because it will take any string as proper object" - yeah, that was the "shut-up warning" version, but I can see how in your case you really want to make sure it's a PhoneNumber.

Comment: Not an optimal solution. How would one use multiple formatted phone numbers in a single file/app?

Answer (score 0):

Pydantic does not yet support this: [Source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic-extra-types/issues/107)

[OysterShucker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10292330/oystershucker)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76985202/2166337) is not optimal when you have to use multiple formats or regions for the phone-number types.

The workaround I use is:

```py
from pydantic_extra_types import PhoneNumber as PydanticPhoneNumber
...
PhoneNumber = type(
    "PhoneNumberStr",
    (PydanticPhoneNumber,),
    {   
        "default_region_code": "IN",
        "phone_format": "E164",
    },
)
```

This is the same as:

```py
class PhoneNumber(PydanticPhoneNumber):
    default_region_code="IN"
    phone_format="E164"
```

You can also write a function to further customize it by wrapping any of the above methods inside the function.